# Custom CompletableFuture class - incompatible casting despite having correct return

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool

I need to override `cancel()` method in `CompletableFuture<T>` class because I need to interrupt thread after timeout specified in `get()`. Normal `CompletableFuture<T>` only throws `TimeoutException` after timeout, but threads are still stuck with some infinite task. If there is other solution, please, correct me but currently I am trying to instantiate `FutureImpl<T>`. However, I receive an error with message:

```
class java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture cannot be cast to class FutureImpl (java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; FutureImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I extend `CompletableFuture<T>` like that:

```
public class FutureImpl<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        boolean result = super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
        if (mayInterruptIfRunning && result) {
            System.out.println("Really cancelled");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have snippet of code (it implements method in interface)

```
@Override
    @Async("Executor")
    public FutureImpl<String> process() {
        FutureImpl<String> newFuture = new FutureImpl<String>();
        System.out.println(newFuture.getClass());

        try {
            //Do something long
            newFuture.complete("RESULT");

        } catch (Exception exc){
            newFuture.completeExceptionally(exc);
        }
        return newFuture;
    }
}
```

And I also have this snippet of code:

```
    @Inject
    private WorkerService workerService;

    //An example PostMapping for service test in Postman
    @GetMapping
    @Async("TARWS-Executor")
    public void testService() {
        FutureImpl<String> future = workerService.process();

        try {
            future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException exc) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is the error? I don't see a cast.

Comment: Possibly some code (e.g., some decorator/proxy?) is invoking a method on your `FutureImpl` (e.g., `thenAccept`) and that's returning a plain `CompletableFuture`. If that's the case, then try overriding [`newIncompleteFuture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#newIncompleteFuture()) as well and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: But note your override of `cancel` is not doing what you think. `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` is interrupting the thread which called `cancel`, not the thread that's executing the future's action.

Comment: Then how may I interrupt thread that is executing future's action? I don't want to double up threads' number